# How to handle exception in flatmap - reactive spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-reactive

See this code:

```
somePostRequest
  .bodyToMono(String.class)
  .flatMap(token -> Mono.just(addTokenToMap(token,bankCode)));
```

Problem here is that the method: `addTokenToMap()` - needs to be wrapped in try catch block - which I am looking to avoid. Is there a way to handle this with perhaps `doOnError()` or something similar?

Comment: No, you need to expand the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a functional interface and a helper method then you can make your call site avoid the try-catch.

It might be overkill if you're only needing to use it once, but if you need to do the same thing a lot then it could save you a bit of typing.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ThrowableSupplier<T> {
    T get() throws Throwable;
}

public static <T> Consumer<MonoSink<T>> sink(ThrowableSupplier<T> supplier) {
    return sink -> {
        try {
            sink.success(supplier.get());
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
            sink.error(throwable);
        }
    };
}
```

Your code becomes

```
Mono.create(sink(() -> addTokenToMap(token, bankCode)));
```